# Custom standard deviation implementation in R

Tags: r, function

I am creating custom standard deviation for computing summary statistics in R, for both unbiased and biased estimates. For the biased estimate, I am getting different values from my function and from the in-built function.

Code:

```
My.Sd = function(x) {
    sqrt(sum((x - (sum(x) / length(x)))^2) / length(x))
}

#Sanity check
My.Sd(0:10)
```

The above yields:

```
> My.Sd(0:10)
[1] 3.162278
```

And the primitive:

```
> sd(0:10)
[1] 3.316625
```

Why is there a difference or am I computing something wrongly in `My.Sd()`?

Comment: Is there any way that I can obtain the same value as `sd()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's because `sd` is for sample standard deviation,  you need n-1 obs, try using `length(x)-1`

```
My.Sd = function(x) {
  sqrt(sum((x - (sum(x) / length(x)))^2) / (length(x)-1))
}
> My.Sd(0:10)
[1] 3.316625
> sd(0:10)
[1] 3.316625
```